# Storing logical conditions in a dictionary and passing them to if statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary of logical conditions, i.e. a == 1, that I need to use in an if statement for evaluation.  This may not be possible, but I wanted to find out for sure.  Sample code:

```
z = {'var1':['a == 1'],
     'var2':['b == 3']
    }
a = 6
b = 20

#If I use the dictionary value in an if statement like this:

if z['var1']:
    print 'TRUE'
else:
    print 'FALSE'

#It will always evaluate as true.  What I want is for the statement to
#translate into the following form:

if a == 1:
    print 'TRUE'
else:
    print 'FALSE'
```

I have been searching various permutations on if statements, list comprehensions and string manipulation, but I haven't found results matching this problem. If it is not possible, I'd like to know.  If there is a better approach, I'd like to know that as well.  Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your if statement is true because a string is always true. Martjin Peters answer works, try it.

Comment: How is the dictionary filled? If it's predefined, then it makes no sense to me to complicate the code like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to store a expression, so it is possible to use the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function (you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) if you want to play around with statements).

```
>>> a = 6
>>> b = 3

>>> z = {
        'var1':eval('a == 1'),
        'var2':eval('b == 3'),
    }

>>> if z['var1']:
        print "True!"
    else:
        print "False!"
False!

>>> if z['var2']:
        print "True!"
    else:
        print "False!"
True!
```

Note that you need to assign your variables before you create the expressions inside your dictionary, as the expression is evaluated at run-time, so a `NameError` exception will be raised if the variable doesn't exist in memory.

```
>>> eval(foo)
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Also be wary that `eval()` can be dangerous if you allow users to input arbitrary strings as its argument. More about that [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

To quickly explain why your original code is always returning `True`, the boolean expression your `if` statement is evaluating is a list containing one string. Python evaluates all non-empty sequences as `True`, so you satisfy the condition and the string TRUE is printed.

```
>>> z['var1']
['a == 1']

>>> bool(z['var1'])
True
```

Comment: I am required by the laws of the python users on SO to say that you should avoid `eval` if user input will be passed to it.  In this case it looks fine since they are hard-coded strings, but I felt the disclaimer was necessary.

Comment: I did include that in my answer... with a link to Ned Batchelder's blog post on the subject

Comment: Yup, I see that know.  I like to be the first person to make a comment about `eval` because I know someone will do it eventually, and not everyone phrases things in a nice way on this site.  Sorry about the double warning.

Comment: No problem it is worth emphasising I suppose :)

Comment: I should have clarified that the dictionary containing the expressions is NOT open to user input.  Additionally, this is a tool that will only live on my machine.  Not an excuse for sloppy design, but some context. Thanks for your most useful response. My life just got a little easier.

Comment: No problem - if my reply helped you feel free to upvote it / mark as the answer, so this question then becomes closed.

Answer (score 7):

You can store *functions* in a dictionary:

```
z = {'var1': lambda a, b: a == 1,
     'var2': lambda a, b: b == 3,
    }

if z['var1'](a, b):
    print 'TRUE'

# etc.
```

I used `lambda` functions here, but full-blown functions would work too.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit the code, but you made a minor mistake. There shouldn't be a comma at the last item in the dictionary.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen that makes no difference in Python. Trailing commas are fine.